# PHP symlink() fails on Windows 7

Tags: php, windows-7, symlink

PHP symlink() function fails on Windows 7 with the error:

```
Warning: symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\…\lib\model\doctrine\Website.class.php
```

It's a XAMPP server on with PHP 5.3.8.

From the symlink() documentation:

> 5.3.0  This function is now available on Windows platforms (Vista, Server 2008 or greater).

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Permissions issue maybe? Try with UAC turned off and Xampp running as administrator.

Comment: Not the case unfortunately, the user is an administrator, folder is writable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a bug in PHP 5.3 according to this:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48975

and this:

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,64011 (reply #2)

Maybe you could upgrade to PHP 5.4 and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we'll give it a run shortly.

Comment: Absolute niceness, it worked! XAMPP update to the PHP version 5.4.7 fixed it. Thanks a lot Alex!

Comment: Alex, if you have a spare minute, I'd appreciate if you took a look at another case/bug with symlinks on Windows 7 http://stackoverflow.com/q/13379645/1373324 Could be that you've experienced this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
//symlink($target, $link);
exec('mklink /j "' . str_replace('/', '\\', $link) . '" "' . str_replace('/', '\\', $target) . '"');
```

Comment: The option `/j` creates symlinks to folders - for files (as needed in this case) use `/H` instead - see: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Answer (score 0):

About PHP CLI on windows OS:
Do not forget to start the console with `Run as Administrator` else `symlink` will return `false` and raise the following error:

```
Warning: symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314)
```