# filetype() returns dir for symlinks on Windows 7

Tags: php, windows-7, symlink

Regardless of the [filetype()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filetype.php) documentation, PHP 5.4.7 returns "dir" on symlinks on Windows 7.

What's the most reliable way to detect a symlink on Windows 7?

Comment: I think that is an apache/php issue. Maybe try a newer version of apache/php. Linking in windows is a "new" thing. Not as old and sophisticated as in Linux, so the older windows version of apache/php can't handle it. But that is just a guess.

Comment: Good call, symlinks didn't work at all before this was done http://stackoverflow.com/q/13376319/1373324

Answer (score 3):

what does [is_link()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-link.php) return in your case? maybe you can use that to test for links.

The provided link ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-link.php ) contains a workaround for Windows in the first comment. It's ugly, but I guess it does the job.

Comment: Good call, tried it, the same. filetype() is probably using the same callback as is_link()

Comment: The problem with the kludge is always the fact that you can't rely on them in the long term. If Microsoft will change its LNK behaviour in the filesystem, you have a broken system. A PHP provided straightforward solution would at least offer legacy support, but currently it's even buggy :(