# Magento + modman = 503 network error in checkout onepage

Tags: php, linux, windows, magento, modman

I have a problem installing modman on our Enterprise Magento store.
We have two servers one on Linux and one on Windows (we have them like that for testing purposes). 
I am having problem with the server running on windows. 
The problem is that when I am trying to buy something from the magento shop running on Windows sometimes I am getting a 503 network error and in the error logs is saying that "Module "XXX" requires module "YYY"." 
I checked if the modules are there and they are I made all the files to be readable and writable - so the problem is not about rights. 
Also its not always the same modules missing, they are changing, but are from the one that I transformed with modman.

The interesting part is that sometimes I am able to complete my order normally without having any problems.

On the other hand in the Linux server is working normally always.

What can be the problem ? I saw this :

[PHP symlink() fails on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376319/php-symlink-fails-on-windows-7)

that maybe its a bug from the PHP because on the windows server I am with PHP 5.3.9 and on the Linux one I am with 5.3.10.

Please if somebody knows what the problem could be to help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: modman is using symlinks and I belive that indeed is the problem. Perhaps copying the files manually after modman has downloaded them would work?

Are the modules listed in the backend? System -> Configuration -> Advanced?

Comment: Yes the modules are there listed. What I think is happening is that sometimes is it's not able to find the symlinks or the path that this symlink is representing. I can see that is usually making problem for only a few files so I double checked them and they look fine and also as I said sometimes I am able to finish my order which should not be possible if the symlinks do not exist. If you have any other suggestions do not hesitate tell me or to ask me.

Comment: I found a solution but sadly not really elegant. The problem was that somehow the configuration files that are having inside the tag <depends> which means that the module depends from another module and this module is also converted to modman then somehow in Windows only the dependent files cannot be found. Still I am will dig more in this but until now the solution is just to put the original configuration files. If somebody have a solution or any ideas, please let share them. :)

Comment: Thanks @user3099779 your solution of copying the app/etc/modules config files over works for me, this is a constant issue for me on checkout where it shows the module dependency errors. A real solution would be great, I will even add a bounty. I suggest the title be changed to Windows Modman Module Requires Module Dependency Error on Checkout

Answer (score -1):

There is an option at **System > Configuration > Developer > Template Settings > Allow Symlinks** that you can enable.

Comment: yes that is already enabled, or else modman would not work at all.