# The symlink() function is not available on your system

Tags: symfony

When I run `php app/console assets:install web --symlink` command I got

The symlink() function is not available on your system. You need to install the assets without the --symlink option.

I installed "Link Shell Extension" but it does not help.

Comment: What version of symfony2 are you using? `php app/console --version`

Answer (score 0):

There is no symlink option for XP https://www.php.net/symlink

> Note: Windows users should note that this function will only work if the system you run PHP from is Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008 or newer. Windows versions prior to that does not support symbolic links.

[And search next time :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894790/symfony2-and-assetics-symlink-on-windows-7)